# Detect calypso card from other EMV type B cards?

Tags: nfc, emv, calypso

How to detect Calypso card from other emv type B cards.

Calypso type cards which is a PICC compliant with ISO/IEC 14443-4 type B cards.

We would like to detect the card is not a EMV card, before processing by the EMV kernel.

from the ATQB structure of the Calypso card, is there a way we can find?

We read ATQB from calypso card,

```
`            .cardType         = CARDTYPE_TYPE_B (6)          
             .atqb             = 12:{50AA0701 AB000000 00004191}
             .ata              = 1:{00}
`
```

for a Visa card that is type B

```
`  .cardType          = CARDTYPE_TYPE_B (6)             
   .atqb             = 12:{50C5D69F 00000000 00006183}
   .ata              = 1:{00}`
```

So we cant find a tangible difference between PICC of calypso or Visa card. How to identify the card on detect and accept only EMV and not further process calypso card?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can recognize an EMV by sending a select PSSE command to the card:

`a4 04 00 0e 32 50 41 59 2e 53 59 53 2e 44 44 46 30 31 00`

`a4:` select command

Try to select `2PAY.SYS.DDF`

If `2PAY.SYS.DDF` is in the card response, the card is an EMV card.

Comment: Are you shure that "2PAY.SYS.DDF is in the card response", ? Usually an EMV card responds with a "File Control Information (FCI) Template" that starts with "6F 3A .." but never responses the "2PAY.SYS.DDF" data.

Comment: In the File Control Information Template, you can find the Dedicated File name
For example,
https://emvlab.org/tlvutils/?data=6F2F840E325041592E5359532E4444463031A51DBF0C1A61184F07A0000000031010500A564953412044454249548701019000

Comment: Thanks, I never mentioned that 84 Dedicated File (DF) Name contains "2PAY.SYS.DDF" :-)

Comment: If we give EMV Select with 2PAY.SYS.DDF01,
If the directory is present on the card, the card will send back in ADPU-response PPSE SW1/SW2 = 9000 (ОК)
If the directory is missing on the card, in the APDU-R SW1/SW2 will be = 6A82 (File not found). 
If the file Not Found, we can identify as non EMV cards

Comment: That's not so easy, some Desfire cards respond 9000 but don't have 2PAY.SYS.DDF01 in the response